# JSON and Property List (plist) compatibility?

Tags: android, ios, json, serialization, plist

I am designing an iPhone app that provides services to the same app running on another device over wifi by HTTP.

My plan is to provide a few APIs and return results for queries in the format of Plist, which is supported on most iOS devices. However, in the future, it is very likely that Android version will come up.

To support both devices, it seems that JSON is a better choice, considering the prime time of iOS 5+ is coming, older version of iOS waning.

My question is:

Are these two formats of serialization compatible?

What is the potential catch(, if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are talking about the old-style plist format, as in `{ "array" = ( 1, 2, 3 }; value = "text" }`. This looks a lot like JSON on the surface, but there are several differences (like =; instead of :, in objects). So, a parser for one will not be able to natively handle the other.

On the other hand, if all you are using is arrays and objects/dictionaries, then both formats are able to express exactly the same data structures. So, starting out using one format you can easily switch to the other.

Comment: I'm talking about implementing serialization of NSDictionary/NSArray/NSNumber instances with NSPropertyListSerialization and NSJSONSerialization APIs, and making an android app providing the similar feature.

Comment: In that case I would recommend that you use JSON from the start. On Android you'll be able to deserialize the same data as Map/List/Number values.